# Not sure on what length Text field in mysql should have

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, text

In my Mysql DB I have a field which is used to store user-inputted text, and therefore set as Text and not varchar.

A user can input a maximum of 3000 characters which is then saved into the Text field.

So, should I give the Text field an length of 3000 in Mysql? Since thats the maximum characters a user can submit. More or less like length with varchar works.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL text field can store a maximum of 65535 characters (using single-byte characters).

You don't need to specify a text field's length like you do for varchar.

Comment: But in order to add a Index key to the text field. Do I have to set a length first? Coz right now I cant add a index key to the text field, or that might be just coz it is a text field.

Comment: TEXT columns can be indexed but a prefix length must be given.  

Example:  
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON myfield (key(10));`  
This example indexes just the first 10 characters.